# custom error message shows and disappears on submit

Tags: javascript, html, validation, flask

I am using flask, html, css and javascript. So what I did was enter a error message in my login form as a new  and set display: none. I validate the input credential by comparing values from a SQLite database i set previously. This validation is done inside the flask. When the form is submitted, it is validated inside the flask, however I created a javascript that changes the styling for the error message to display: block. This would show the error message for incorrect fields and the correct input users will be redirected to a new page and hence they wont see the error.

So I was hoping that the error message shows after the form is submitted for the login and the users that key in the right information will be redirected.

Flask:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def tutor_login():
    tutor_login_form = LoginAccount(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and tutor_login_form.validate():
        session.pop('user', None)

    admin_account = Admin.query.all()
    tutor_account = Tutor.query.all()
    for i in admin_account:
        admin_id = i.admin_id_num
        for j in tutor_account:
            tutor_id = j.tutor_id_num
            if admin_id == tutor_login_form.id_num.data:
                admin_info = Admin.query.filter_by(admin_id_num=tutor_login_form.id_num.data).first()
                admin_pass = admin_info.admin_password

                if admin_pass == tutor_login_form.password.data:
                    session['user'] = tutor_login_form.id_num.data

                    return redirect(url_for('admin_main'))

            elif tutor_id == tutor_login_form.id_num.data:
                tutor_info = Tutor.query.filter_by(id_num=tutor_login_form.id_num.data).first()
                tutor_pass = tutor_info.tutor_password

                if tutor_pass == tutor_login_form.password.data:
                    session['user'] = tutor_login_form.id_num.data

                    return redirect(url_for('retrieve_tutor_account'))

    return render_template('tutorlogin.html')
```

HTML:

```
<form class="" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="validate()">
                                        <!-- Input fields -->
                                        <div class="form-group mt-3">
                                            <label for="id_num">Enter Tutor ID:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_num" placeholder="Enter Tutor ID" name="id_num">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group my-3">
                                            <label for="password">Enter Password:</label>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-3 text-center" id="error">
                                            ID or Password entered is invalid! Please try again.
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="text-center">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-customized">Login</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <p class="text-center my-3">Forgot your password? <br> <a href="">Click here to reset</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var error = document.getElementById('error');

    function validate(){
        error.style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `form` represents a hyperlink, submitting a form navigates to a new page. You've to prevent the form submission, if any validation errors occur.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate the credentials without a page reload, you need to use Ajax requests.

Where on clicking Submit, the JavaScript will first check if all fields all valid and filled and then send an Ajax request to the Flask app.

Depending on the response of the query you can either show a error message or redirect user to the page you want.

Here's a YouTube video for reference - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmC26YXExJ4